# Less multiple files import

Tags: css, less

I'm working on WordPress theme that needs to have color schemes functionality.
I am forced to use less on this project. I have file called schemes.less, that contains code for styling different colored sections on a webpage.
Then I have set of less files called: dark.less, light.less, blue.less etc.
I am importing them using default values technique (http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-default-variables), but because of lazy loading if I import the scheme.less multiple times every time I have the same variables.

Are there any ways to workaround that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isolate themes from each other with "unnamed" namespaces:

```
& {
    @import (multiple) "schemes.less"
    @import "dark.less";
}

& {
    @import (multiple) "schemes.less"
    @import "light.less";
}

// etc.
```

(Assuming you're using an up-to-date Less compiler, not `lessphp` - for that one you need minor modifications - e.g. remove `(multiple)` etc.).

Comment: I'm sorry seven-phases-max but I don't understand how this run with the same unmaned namespace without overriding. Please, can you provide a possible "final result" of your code? Thanks

Comment: Well, obviously the result is vastly depending on what is content of those files. Above is just a simplified example to illustrate how to isolate scopes, though it's not problem to craft a minimalistic (and thus artificial) example - https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/539141a461adb91ca738 (click link there).

Comment: Thanks seven-phases-max