# less css avoid globalized variable

Tags: css, less

I'm looking for the best way to avoid globally diffused variables.

I made a test with this configuration:

**_import.less**

```
@test: #FFF;
```

**_import2.less**

```
@test: #000;
```

**test.less**

```
@import (reference) "_import";

body {
    background: @test;
}
```

**test2.less**

```
@import (reference) "_import2";

div {
    background: @test;
}
```

**index.less**

```
@import "test";
@import "test2";
```

The output with `lessc index.less test.css` still looks like

```
body {
  background: #000;
}
div {
  background: #000;
}
```

But what I'm looking for is:

```
body {
  background: #FFF;
}
div {
  background: #000;
}
```

Using less 2.7 or 3.9 give the same behavior.
Do someone know a solution?
Thanks

Comment: This is by design: *When defining a variable twice, the last definition of the variable is used, searching from the current scope upwards.* [ref](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-evaluation) If you want to avoid it, use a different variable, or import your files dynamically (based on a condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always isolate the scope of anything (incl. an imported file) using "unnamed namespace", i.e. `& {}`, block.

E.g.:

*test.less*:

```
@import "_import";

body {
    background: @test;
}
```

*test2.less*:

```
@import "_import2";

div {
    background: @test;
}
```

*index.less*:

```
& {@import "test";}
& {@import "test2";}
```

Depending on your goals these `& {}` blocks can be moved right into the `test` files themselves.

### ---

Ref: [Local Variable Scoping in Import Files](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2442#issuecomment-73839112)

Comment: this is interesting. didn't know about this. What would be an example of a good reason to use this? I find that the OP wouldn't even benefit, because why import it at all if your going to scope it out?

Comment: @soulshined I guess a typical use case is to merge unrelated libraries/components (using same variable names) into one. And/or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26589509/2712740).

Comment: Just thanks, it's awesome. Doc should be improved because there's no way to find is easily